# Pandas: Convert Dict of Lists with DatetimeIndex to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help from pandas experts :) 
I need to *efficiently* create DataFrame from dictionary that contains list of two DatetimeIndexes as values.

Here is short example of such dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
  871:[pd.date_range('20180131', '20180331', freq='M', normalize=True),
       pd.date_range('20180228', '20180430', freq='M', normalize=True)],
  872:[pd.date_range('20180228', '20180331', freq='M', normalize=True),
       pd.date_range('20180331', '20180430', freq='M', normalize=True)]}

d
Out[3]: 
{871: [DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M'),
  DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')],
 872: [DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-28', '2018-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M'),
  DatetimeIndex(['2018-03-31', '2018-04-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')]}
```

What I want to get is a DataFrame where dict keys used as indexes and two pd.Timestamp columns that correspond to those two DatetimeIndexes from above.

Here is how it should look like:

```
result_df
Out[6]: 
         Start        End
871 2018-01-31 2018-02-28
871 2018-02-28 2018-03-31
871 2018-03-31 2018-04-30
872 2018-02-28 2018-03-31
872 2018-03-31 2018-04-30
```

**P.S.**
Actual task is to split large DataFrame with date ranges, such as below, to single months.

```
df_original
Out[19]: 
           Start        End
Index                      
871   2018-01-31 2018-02-28
872   2018-02-28 2018-04-30
```

Large is several hundred thousand rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
d1 = {k: pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*v)), columns=['Start','End']) for k, v in d.items()}
df = pd.concat(d1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df)
         Start        End
871 2018-01-31 2018-02-28
871 2018-02-28 2018-03-31
871 2018-03-31 2018-04-30
872 2018-02-28 2018-03-31
872 2018-03-31 2018-04-30
```

Comment: It is currently implemented almost exactly like this. Is there some option to construct DataFrame without looping over dict items?

Comment: @AlexanderM. - i think not.